# jMeter java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File example.csv must exist and be readable

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I updated jMeter 2.9 to 3.2 and having issues with old test cases. When I open .jmx file with jMeter 2.9 all tests runs smoothly, but when using version 3.2 from same location I get a message: The file jmeter-results.xml already exists, what do you want to do? Append to existing file - Don't start - Overwrite existing file.
Doesn't matter what I choose, it doesn't work.

Log file:

```
2017-07-28 11:55:20,458 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2017-07-28 11:55:20,458 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: 
[]
2017-07-28 11:55:20,474 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, 
*local*)
2017-07-28 11:55:20,567 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 
ThreadGroup: 1 : JMeter Users
2017-07-28 11:55:20,567 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 
threads for group JMeter Users.
2017-07-28 11:55:20,567 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will 
continue on error
2017-07-28 11:55:20,567 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... 
number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=5 perThread=5000.0 delayedStart=false
2017-07-28 11:55:20,567 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group 
number 1
2017-07-28 11:55:20,567 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups 
have been started
2017-07-28 11:55:20,583 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: JMeter 
Users 1-1
2017-07-28 11:55:20,583 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Stored: testdata/test.csv
2017-07-28 11:55:20,583 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Test failed!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File test.csv must exist and be readable
at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.createBufferedReader(FileServer.java:430) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getReader(FileServer.java:396) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getParsedLine(FileServer.java:378) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
at org.apache.jmeter.config.CSVDataSet.iterationStart(CSVDataSet.java:200) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:3.2 r1790748]
at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterationStart(GenericController.java:393) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterEvents(GenericController.java:385) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:158) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:123) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.AbstractThreadGroup.next(AbstractThreadGroup.java:87) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:252) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_141]
2017-07-28 11:55:20,583 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: JMeter 
Users 1-1
2017-07-28 11:55:20,583 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test 
listeners of end of test
2017-07-28 11:55:20,583 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, 
*local*)
```

Comment: File testdata/test.csv is used for read and also write?

Comment: Yes, with all rights.

Comment: `Stored: testdata/test.csv` why do you assume relative path will work?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are talking about this warning:

   [image: JMeter file exists]

   it is enhancement introduced in [JMeter 3.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-32) within the bounds of [issue 58164](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58164). Just remove all the listeners from your Test Plan and the warning will go away. Actually you don't need to have any listeners as [they create overhead and may ruin your test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing), consider storing your test result to .jtl result file using [-l command-line argument instead](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options).
2. Looking into this line:

   > 2017-07-30 14:29:57,918 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Stored: **testdata/test.csv**

   you simply forgot to copy your `test.csv` file to new JMeter installation

   - Go to the JMeter 3.2 "bin" folder
   - Create folder `testdata` there
   - Copy your `test.csv` file into the `testdata` folder

   Or just use the absolute path to your `test.csv` file.

Comment: How to copy? Because when I am doing `<mkdir dir="${basedir}/target/jmeter/bin/testdata" />
        <copy file="${basedir}/src/test/jmeter/testdata/checklist.csv" 
           todir="${basedir}/target/jmeter/bin/testdata" />` it creates every required file folder in bin folder except testdata. I am on windows and I am using admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

Place the .csv file in the path were you have your scripts and change the fully qualified CSV path with just .csv filename.