# Jmeter: Test plan which was working in windows failing in Centos

Tags: jmeter, maven-3, centos7

I have a test plan which has two threads.

Each thread takes two CSV files as test data.

I have provided the CSV path as `\testdata\csvtest1.csv` this directory is located at `src\test\jmeter\testdata`, when I run this plan it works in Windows both in GUI mode and in non-gui mode via maven `mvn clean verify`.

But when I run this in Centos 7, it is giving below error I found in logs.

```
2018-10-04 13:56:24,739 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Stored: \testdata\csvtest1.csv
2018-10-04 13:56:24,743 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Stored: \testdata\csvtest2.csv
2018-10-04 13:56:24,740 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Test failed!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File \testdata\csvtest2.csv must exist and be readable
```

So I manually copy-pasted test data directory with both CSV files inside Jmeter's bin directory. Still, it is giving the same error.

I have also tried solution here [jMeter java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File example.csv must exist and be readable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45370404/jmeter-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-file-example-csv-must-exist-and-be-re) and commented on answer but it didnt work.

Am I doing something wrong?

**POM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.demo.performancetesting</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-performance-testing</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                        <resultsFileFormat>xml</resultsFileFormat>
                        <generateReports>false</generateReports>
                    </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-graph-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <inputFile>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results/*.jtl</inputFile>
                    <graphs>
                        <graph>
                            <pluginType>ResponseTimesOverTime</pluginType>
                            <width>800</width>
                            <height>600</height>
                            <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results/BlazeDemoRequest.png</outputFile>
                        </graph>
                    </graphs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: try using slashes `/testdata/csvtest2.csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to read [documentation](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/blob/master/README.md#reference-jmx-files-and-csv-data)?

> Reference JMX files and CSV data
>
> Once you have created your JMeter tests, you'll need to copy them to `<Project Dir>/src/test/jmeter`. By default this plugin will pick up all the .jmx files in that directory, to specify which tests should be run please see the project documentation.
> **You can also put data files in this folder and reference them in your plan**.

So:

1. Copy your `csvtest1.csv`, `csvtest2.csv`, etc to the same location where your .jmx test(s) live, to wit `src/test/jmeter` folder
2. Reference them in the CSV Data Set Config elements just by name, i.e. `csvtest1.csv`

See [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) article for more information on various approaches to running JMeter tests, including using JMeter Maven Plugin.

Comment: Putting csv files in besides jmx file and giving filename directly - this approach worked, but let question have more answers on why relative path is not working.

Comment: Who told you relative path doesn't work? The path must be relative to `target/jmeter/testFiles` folder, that's it. If you want to keep CSV files like `src/test/jmeter/testdata/csvtest1.csv` you will need to refer them as `testdata/csvtest1.csv`. If you want to keep them elsewhere - feel free to use the relative path, but again it **has to be relative to target/jmeter/testdata folder**. If you cannot come up with the correct path yourself - share your full JMeter Maven project location and full location of the CSV file - maybe someone will help you to build the correct relative path

Comment: Please take a break, timeout. Seems you're fedup answering questions. In the mean time I'll try testing what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use / (slash) as file separator and make sure the files are readable from the user executing the test plan.

Comment: I didnt get you. Use slash as file separator. I using relative path like this `/testdata/csvtest2.csv`

Comment: But you are posting output like this: "2018-10-04 13:56:24,739 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Stored: \testdata\csvtest1.csv" coming from centos. So I guess you may have backslashes somewhere...

Comment: you mean I need to use forward slash (/) ??

Comment: Of course. LInux file separator is "/". If you are only using slashes within your Java code, it will usually work on Windows and Linux, since the VM will take care. You only have to consider the system file separator e.g. when forking a process via exec and you have to pass a file as argument.